# Define a function or loop, which restarts if given integer-parameter is less than X, or refuses to accept value less than 3

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm writing a simple program where a person can go on a trip, but the trip has to last `3` days *minimum*. The whole program has more parts which all work well, and the whole program works, but now I want to enhance it and set the minimal parameter value of function `hotel_cost(days)` to `3`

In it's most basic form, my function is:

```
def hotel_cost(days):
    # hotel costs 140$ per day
    return 140 * int(days)
```

And the above obviously works, but I want to change it so that it does not accept less than 3.

I'm experimenting with while and a boolean but it gives me `None`, and I've also faced accidental infinite recursion. Sorry if this question is too basic, it's my first one. I tried searching but to no avail.

Comment: While your not showing what you've experimented, we cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can condense asking the user for the number of days, and giving them there price in in one function.

```
def ask_num_hotel_days():
    i = int(input("Enter nuber of days: "))
    while(i < 3):
        print(str(i) + " is not a valid number of days")
        i = int(input("Enter nuber of days: "))
    return 140 * i
```

Comment: Ha! Yes! It works! And the code is so simple and understandable, too. I knew the answer would be simple, but my step by step logic must've been flawed. If only I realised that I can simply call `i = int(.......)` again and it won't break. I tried the `while` and even `try, except` but I just could not grasp it in a situation where all of this is combined with `input`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, you can do this:

```
def hotel_cost(days):
    if int(days) >= 3:
        return 140 * int(days)
    else:
        return False
```

And then you can do:

```py
while not hotel_cost(days):
     print("How many days are you staying?")
     days = input()
```

Once it gets out of the while, the days amount will be valid, as well as the cost.

**EDIT :**
I wrote the code inside the while loop, to be more clear about what I suggested.

I hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: You method is almost right, except that the line`days >= 3` gives a `TypeError`. Change is to `int(days) >= 3`.

Comment: Sure Thing. That brain, always getting ahead of the fingers ;)

Comment: Returning flag values is a C-ism that's frowned on in Python (in general, you return a single type on success or raise an exception on failure, you don't have multiple return types at all, let alone different return types for success and failure). In any reasonable program, you'd want to change `return False` to something like `raise ValueError("Trips must be at least three days long; received {}".format(days))`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point. Although that solution may be over the OP's head.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But what do you mean by:
    while not hotel_cost(days):
         # get input again
while requires an indented block of code, and I don't understand what are you proposing here.

Right now I have:
`def hotel_cost(days):`
        `if days >= 3:`
            `return 140 * int(days)`
        `else:`
            `return False`
        `while not hotel_cost(days):`
            
    `print hotel_cost(int(raw_input("How many days You'll be staying?\n")))`
(Edit: why comments do not accept indents?)

Comment: The reasons for avoiding flag values are: (1) Constant tests for flags means your (common) success path runs slower (the failure path might be faster, but optimizing the unexpected case is silly) and (2) You don't know how high up the stack you'll have to go before someone knows how to deal with failure; it might not be your caller at all, and if you're using flag values, then every layer between the flag returning function and the handler has to test for and pass along the failure manually; with exceptions, only the raising and catching functions need to do anything at all.

Comment: @Aleksik: Your code isn't storing a `days` variable, so the `while` test and the calculation are mismatched. You'd want something like `days = int(raw_input("How many days You'll be staying?\n"))`, `while not hotel_cost(days):` `days = int(raw_input("You must stay at least three days: How many days You'll be staying?\n"))`, and after the `while` loop, `print days`. The important part is to store the input in `days` so it can be used twice, once to verify the function succeeds, and again to `print`.

Comment: @Aleksik: Comments are dumb like that, they don't accept newlines to keep them compact.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, @ShadowRanger. I tried to be as more simplistic as possible, due to the apparent knowledge of the op.